# Error: Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have the code below:

```
public ActionResult OnDemand()
{
    List<SiteMenu> all = new List<SiteMenu>();
    using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
    {
        all = dc.SiteMenus.Where(a => a.ParentMenuID.Equals(0)).ToList();
    }

    return View(all);
}
```

...but I get the error: Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

...the error occurs on the following line:

```
all = dc.SiteMenus.Where(a => a.ParentMenuID.Equals(0)).ToList();
```

Could I get some help as to what I'm doing wrong? ...Thanks in Advance

Comment: Apparently `ParentMenuID` is not an integer. Try using equality operator `==` instead of `Equals` and see if any compile-time errors appears.

Answer (score 2):

This should work fine:

```
all = dc.SiteMenus.Where(a => a.ParentMenuID == 0).ToList();
```

As the exception states: Only *primitive types* or *enumeration types* are supported in this context. Which means `ParentMenuID` is an [object type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx).

It should be either a [primitive type](http://condor.depaul.edu/sjost/nwdp/notes/cs1/CSDatatypes.htm) or an [enumeration type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/enumeration-types) in order to use `.Equals()`.